# Publish/Consume: Wait on Subscribe, filter messages and Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactivex

Using Rx.Net 3

With use of the Quartz.Net Scheduler I build a workflow manager to chain jobs (using Quartz Joblistener on finished jobs) with an embedded web server.
The application instantiates an instance of a Subject (singleton).

A web service takes data and starts a workflow, injecting a unique ID. This unique ID is propagated through the workflow.
The Joblistener delegate detects the end of a specific job and calls OnNext on the injected Subject instance with a Type holding the unique ID and an DB table ID.

The idea was that the web service on each call subscribes to the Subject and waits for incoming messages/events and filters them on the unique ID. When found disposes the subscription, collects and returns the generated data to the caller.

How can I make my Subscribe() wait for incoming messages, filter them and Dispose(), without finishing the web service prematurely.

Comment: You need to show us our code. We can't answer this without it. You need an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// model
public class AsyncCommunicationObject
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    public AsyncCommunicationObject(string key, string value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}

// injectable singleton 
public static Subject<AsyncCommunicationObject> AsyncCommunication { get; set; } = new Subject<AsyncCommunicationObject>();

// in web service           
System.Threading.EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
string yourID = some ID

var subscription = _asyncCommunication (injected)
    .Where(x => x.Key == yourID)
    .Take(1)
    .Subscribe(
        x =>
        {
            dbId = x.Value;
            waitHandle.Set();
        }
    );

_schedulerCore.ExecuteJob(upload.JobId, jobDataMap);

waitHandle.WaitOne();
waitHandle.Reset();

subscription.Dispose();

// in job listener
_asyncCommunication.OnNext(new AsyncCommunicationObject(your ID, some value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dispose of the subscription manually.
Any bounding operator like `Take` or `First` signals `OnCompleted` which causes the sequence to be disposed. You can also use `await` observables to make avoid writing callbacks.

For example, 
`dbId = await AsyncCommunication.FirstAsync(x => x.Key == id)`

Comment: thx for providing some internal behaviour. Although i would have a concurrency problem. I need to subscribe, call the job scheduler and await the event. When calling the job scheduler first i could miss the event when using FirstAsync().